# Forcing a JAXBException in JUnit test

Tags: java, exception, junit

I'm trying to make a JUnit exception test for an unmarshalling method.

This is my unmarshalling method (note: I am returning a String because of normal testing unmarshalling testing with expected string).

```
public String UnMarshalling(String FILE)
{
    ArrayList<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Match.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Match Match2 = (Match) um.unmarshal(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FILE), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        playerList = Match2.playerList;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return playerList.toString();
}
```

Here are the tests for this method.

```
@Test
public void unMarshallingTest() {
    assertTrue(marshalling.UnMarshalling(matchxml).contains("Petras"));
}

@Test(expected=JAXBException.class)
public void marshallingTestException()
{
        marshalling.UnMarshalling(matchbrokenxml);    
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is sending broken xml so for example with a wrong version of xml and getting `JAXBException`.

So far I have scouted internet for an example but found nothing. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: So are you not getting the expected exception? If `matchbrokenxml` points to a file containing garbage, I'd expect this to work. What is the contents of your file?

Comment: the xml file is empty and i'm getting javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

Comment: So I should change the expected exception to UnmarshalException ?

Comment: There is 20 more exceptions that are linked with that unmarshalexception.

Comment: How should i throw that exception out tho ? @glytching

Comment: Okay so I thing i might have done it. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You are catching and swallowing the exception i.e. `UnMarshalling()` never throws a `JAXBException` (or any subclass of that).

This will work:

```
public String UnMarshalling(String FILE) throws JAXBException {
    ArrayList<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>();
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Match.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Match Match2 = (Match) um.unmarshal(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FILE), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        playerList = Match2.playerList;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

    return playerList.toString();
}


@Test(expected=UnmarshalException.class)
public void marshallingTestException() {

    marshalling.UnMarshalling(matchbrokenxml);

}
```

The main change here is the removal of the catch clause for `JAXBException` and adding `throws JAXBException` to the method declaration.

Your test **strongly** suggests that `JAXBException` is part of the public API for this method, in which case declaring the method to throw `JAXBEception` makes sense. On the other hand if you really do not want or need `JAXBException` in the method signature then your test case is either redundant or is addressing the wrong exception type.